# MP1584 EN pin voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, converter, step-down

The [MP1584EN](http://www.monolithicpower.com/portals/0/documents/products/documents/datasheet/mp1584_r1.0.pdf) datasheet says: Absolute maximum ratings section: All other pin: -0.3V to 6V max. Figure 3 shows the 1.8V typical application. On the picture, there is a voltage divider: between GND and EN: 59k and between EN and VIN 100k.
If the input voltage is high, for example 28V, between GND and EN approximately 10V appears. It's not a problem? The 10V is higher than 6V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a problem because it is a schematic in the datasheet. If you cannot trust that then IC manufacturers would have big problems.

Also, applying a "hard" 10 V, which can deliver a large current at the EN pin might indeed damage the device (I doubt that though). But in this schematic this 10 V is "soft" it cannot deliver much current. So if something on the EN pin would start to conduct, only a small current can flow and nothing will be damaged.

You can check this, build the circuit and apply a Vin which will result in 10 V at the EN input. Now measure that voltage. If it is 10 V then the EN pin can withstand more than 6 V. If the voltage is much below 6 V then the high value of R5 saves the day.

If you're worried, you can adjust the values of R5 and R6 to get a maximum of 6 V on the EN pin. Then watch that EN will be high enough at the lowest Vin.

Comment: As a note, I have seen *numerous* errors in manufacturers data sheets of this type; the description for the pin makes no mention of current injection limits should the abs. max voltage be violated and therefore I would contact the manufacturer as the application circuit is directly violating their own datasheet statements.

Comment: Seconding what @PeterSmith said: whilst datasheet tables are usually rigorously checked, not quite the same checking is usually applied to "theory of operation" section, and example circuits seem to be pretty often drawn by interns (nothing against interns, but they simply lack the error-spotting experience) or some application engineer who's only job was to get the IC to do *anything* interesting, not something stable and reliable, and used unmodified.